# How to find the average of values of all columns of various .csv files keeping only single header and the first label column the same using python?

Tags: python, csv

So I have various .csv files in a directory of the same structure with first row as the header and first column as labels.  Say file 1 is as below:

```
name,value1,value2,value3,value4,......
name1,10,20,0,0,...
name2,20,30,0,0,...
name3,30,40,0,0,...
name4,40,50,0,0,...
....
```

File2:

```
name,value1,value2,value3,value4,......
name1,20,30,0,0,...
name2,30,40,0,0,...
name3,40,50,0,0,...
name4,50,60,0,0,...
....
```

All the .csv files have the same structure with the same number of rows and columns.

What I want is something that looks like this:

```
name,value1,value2,value3,value4,......
name1,15,25,0,0,...
name2,25,35,0,0,...
name3,35,45,0,0,...
name4,45,55,0,0,...
....
```

Where the all the value columns in the last file will be the average of corresponding values in those columns of all the .csv files. So under value1 in the resulting file I should have (10+20+...+...)/n and so on.

The number of .csv files isn't fixed, so I think I'll need a loop.

How do I achieve this with a python script on a Linux machine.

With awk I'm doing this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
    FNR==1 {header=$0}      # header line
    FNR>1 {
        sum[FNR,1] = $1     # names column
        for (j=2; j<=NF; j++) {
            sum[FNR,j] += $j
        }
    }
    END {
        print header
        files = ARGC - 1    # number of csv files
        for (i=2; i<=FNR; i++) {
            $1 = sum[i,1]   # another treatment for the 1st column
            for (j=2; j<=NF; j++) {
                $j = sum[i,j] / files
            }
            print
        }
    }' *.csv
```

But I realized that the column names may not be the same in every file. So say if name1 is present only in first two files & not in the third file then I've to display a message saying it is missing in the third file but still calculate the average from the other two files. 
I think using a dictionary and a counter will do it but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only the standart libraries, here the example is:

import csv
    from statistics import mean

```
filename1 = 'f1.csv'
filename2 = 'f2.csv'
output = 'output.csv'

with open(filename1, 'r') as f1, open(filename2, 'r') as f2, open(output, 'r') as out:
    r1 = csv.reader(f1)
    r2 = csv.reader(f2)
    w = csv.writer(out)
    w.writerows(next(r1))
    next(r2)

    for line1, line2 in zip(r1, r2):
        w.writerows([line1[0]] + list(map(lambda a: (a[0]+a[1])//2, zip(line1[1:], line2[1:]))))
```

If you want to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), here it is:

import pandas as pd

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('filename1.csv', index_col=0, header=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('filename2.csv', index_col=0, header=0)

out = (df1 + df2) // 2

out.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: This is solid. I did not know pandas could simply things *that* much.

Comment: This solution works for two files. What if I've n number of .csv files in a directory that I wanna do this too?

Comment: @s1109 just iterate over them

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the `pandas` option that was [posted by Mr Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55838981/565489), you could also use:

```
filename_list=['csv1.csv','csv2.csv']
dfs=[]
for fname in filename_list:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(fname,index_col=0))

averages = pd.concat([each.stack() for each in dfs],axis=1)\
             .apply(lambda x:x.mean(),axis=1)\
             .unstack()

averages.to_csv("csvAvg.csv")
```